# Need to prove $R^{n+1} \subseteq R^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R$ is a relation on set $U$, Given that $R$ is transitive.

Need to prove $R^{n+1} \subseteq R^n$  for all $n \geq 1$

---

I tried it by Induction

base case for $n=1$

$ R^{2}$  $= R \circ R $   $\qquad$  { Def of exponents }

$\subseteq R $   $\qquad$  { If $R$ is transitive $\Rightarrow (R \circ R) \subseteq R $  }

Now took $I.H$ step as  $R^{n+1} \subseteq R^n$

Took $n=n+1$

$R^{n+2} = R \circ R \circ R^n$     $\qquad$  { Def of exponents }

$\subseteq R \circ R^n $   $\qquad  \qquad  \qquad $  { as If $R$ is transitive $\Rightarrow (R \circ R) \subseteq R $,  and using  monotonicity }

$=R^{n+1}$

Now my question is that I havn't used the $I.H$ step here and was able to prove it just by using  $R$ is transitive $\Rightarrow (R \circ R) \subseteq R $

But below is the prove If I would have done it by using $I.H$

$R^{n+2} = R  \circ R^{n+1}$     $\qquad$  { Def of exponents }

$\subseteq R \circ R^n $   $\qquad  \qquad  \qquad $  { $I.H$ step + monotonicity  }

$=R^{n+1}$

**So which way is correct ?**

Comment: They both are. But if your mission is to use induction, then go with the latter. The inductive proof is a little more elegant in that you don't use $R\circ R\subseteq R$ twice.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for your feed back. And is my base case prove correct because there I have used transitivity.

Comment: Yes the base case is exactly the right thing.